# How to ensure to run some code on same background thread?

Tags: ios, swift, thread-safety, realm, grand-central-dispatch

I am using realm in my iOS Swift project. Search involve complex filters for a big data set. So I am fetching records on background thread.

But realm can be used only from same thread on which Realm was created.
I am saving a reference of results which I got after searching Realm on background thread. This object can only be access from same back thread

How can I ensure to dispatch code at different time to the same thread?

I tried below as suggested to solve the issue, but it didn't worked

```
let realmQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "realm")
    var orginalThread:Thread?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        realmQueue.async {
            self.orginalThread = Thread.current
        }

        let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(2)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {
            self.realmQueue.async {
                print("realm queue after some time")

                if self.orginalThread == Thread.current {
                    print("same thread")
                }else {
                    print("other thread")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Output is

```
realm queue after some time

other thread
```

Comment: Always dispatch on the same GCD queue. Simple as that :)

Comment: Cristik, I have updated question. Operation queue doesn't guarantee same thread

Comment: @Cristik: A GCD queue is not enough. Apple doesn't guarantees that its items are always executed on the same thread (see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW2).

Comment: @Cristik: Yes, I made the same mistake as you. I only added the link as a document to show that it is a feature and not a bug. ;)

Comment: @Atif - Are you 100% sure that you need the same thread? Sometimes people are a bit sloppy with the use of the word "thread". The [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#threading) suggests dispatch queue support, e.g., "Realm objects are not thread safe and cannot be shared across threads, so you must get a Realm instance in each thread/dispatch queue in which you want to read or write." I have a really hard time imaging that Realm is incompatible with basic GCD behaviors. I'd wager that a serial GCD queue would be adequate.

Comment: Rob, Serialized GCD queue can't ensure blocks will be executed on same thread. It will only ensure each operation one by one. When I added blocks at same time in this queue. They were executed on same thread, but when I was adding block randomly at different time in queue these block fired on different thread

Comment: @Atif - (Sigh.) Yes, I know that. You misunderstand what I was saying. I'm questioning your premise that Realm actually was so ignorant of GCD basic operation and actually wrote something that requires it to be on the same thread. I'm suggesting, instead, that even if there might be references to "same thread" in discussions of Realm, the reality might be that GCD serial is actually sufficient (esp since they talk about "each dispatch queue" in the quote I provided).

Answer (score 17):

Here's a small worker class that can works in a similar fashion to async dispatching on a serial queue, with the guarantee that the thread stays the same for all work items.

```
// Performs submitted work items on a dedicated thread
class Worker {

    // the worker thread
    private var thread: Thread?

    // used to put the worker thread in the sleep mode, so in won't consume
    // CPU while the queue is empty
    private let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    // using a lock to avoid race conditions if the worker and the enqueuer threads
    // try to update the queue at the same time
    private let lock = NSRecursiveLock()

    // and finally, the glorious queue, where all submitted blocks end up, and from
    // where the worker thread consumes them
    private var queue = [() -> Void]()

    // enqueues the given block; the worker thread will execute it as soon as possible
    public func enqueue(_ block: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // add the block to the queue, in a thread safe manner
        locked { queue.append(block) }

        // signal the semaphore, this will wake up the sleeping beauty
        semaphore.signal()

        // if this is the first time we enqueue a block, detach the thread
        // this makes the class lazy - it doesn't dispatch a new thread until the first
        // work item arrives
        if thread == nil {
            thread = Thread(block: work)
            thread?.start()
        }
    }

    // the method that gets passed to the thread
    private func work() {
        // just an infinite sequence of sleeps while the queue is empty
        // and block executions if the queue has items
        while true {
            // let's sleep until we get signalled that items are available
            semaphore.wait()

            // extract the first block in a thread safe manner, execute it
            // if we get here we know for sure that the queue has at least one element
            // as the semaphore gets signalled only when an item arrives
            let block = locked { queue.removeFirst() }
            block()
        }
    }

    // synchronously executes the given block in a thread-safe manner
    // returns the same value as the block
    private func locked<T>(do block: () -> T) -> T {
        lock.lock(); defer { lock.unlock() }
        return block()
    }
}
```

Just instantiate it and let it do the job:

```
let worker = Worker()
worker.enqueue { print("On background thread, yay") }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code!  It's very nice and the comments are great.  I wonder if this code or something like it is working for you?  I'm trying to use it and have made two corrections:

1. put in `thread!.start()` right after the Thread is constructed.

2. changed block?() to block() due to the error "Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type '() -> Void'"

If you are using code like this in your own app, maybe you had to make these and other corrections as well?  Would love to know more about what worked for you.  Thank you!

Comment: @dsjoerg thanks for the suggestions, will update the code with them. I think the `removeFirst` method was returning an optional at the time I was writing the code.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create your own thread with a run loop for that. Apple gives an example for [a custom run loop in Objective C](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW5). You may create a thread class in Swift with that like:

```
class MyThread: Thread {
    public var runloop: RunLoop?
    public var done = false

    override func main() {
        runloop = RunLoop.current
        done = false
        repeat {
            let result = CFRunLoopRunInMode(.defaultMode, 10, true)
            if result == .stopped  {
                done = true
            }
        }
        while !done
    }

    func stop() {
        if let rl = runloop?.getCFRunLoop() {
            CFRunLoopStop(rl)
            runloop = nil
            done = true
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
    let thread = MyThread()

    thread.start()
    sleep(1)
    thread.runloop?.perform {
        print("task")
    }
    thread.runloop?.perform {
        print("task 2")
    }
    thread.runloop?.perform {
        print("task 3")
    }
```

**Note**: The `sleep` is not very elegant but needed, since the thread needs some time for its startup. It should be better to check if the property `runloop` is set, and perform the block later if necessary. My code (esp. `runloop`) is probably not safe for race conditions, and it's only for demonstration. ;-)

Comment: Clemens, I tried your suggestion it didn't worked. OperationQueue don't guarantee that it will be dispatch on same thread.

Comment: I have edit question, with code that I run to verify if this solution will work. I also tried to realm using like this, but I got crash saying realm was access from different thread

Comment: @Atif: Sorry and thank you, that's when I learned something. You're absolutely right, and so it says in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW2). I've added a solution with `NSThread`.