# gcd async dispatched queue guarentee on same thread

Tags: swift

I want to know if it’s guaranteed that queue will dispatched on same thread every time if I run `queue.asyncAfter(...)` 40 loops for example.

```swift
for numbers in 1...40 {
    q.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(numbers)){

        NSLog("q async \(Thread.current.isMainThread)  \(Thread.current.qualityOfService) \(Thread.current.description) ")

    }
    q.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(numbers*2)){

        NSLog("q async \(Thread.current.isMainThread)  \(Thread.current.qualityOfService) \(Thread.current.description) ")

    }
}
```

That resulted in:

```
2022-01-16 21:35:17.055 main.exe[10392:a58] q async false  default <Thread: 0x0000018bcce26150> 
2022-01-16 21:35:19.059 main.exe[10392:a58] q async false  default <Thread: 0x0000018bcce26150> 
2022-01-16 21:35:21.052 main.exe[10392:a58] q async false  default <Thread: 0x0000018bcce26150> 
2022-01-16 21:35:23.062 main.exe[10392:a58] q async false  default <Thread: 0x0000018bcce26150> 
2022-01-16 21:35:25.056 main.exe[10392:a58] q async false  default <Thread: 0x0000018bcce26150> 
2022-01-16 21:35:27.062 main.exe[10392:a58] q async false  default <Thread: 0x0000018bcce26150> 
2022-01-16 21:35:29.052 main.exe[10392:a58] q async false  default <Thread: 0x0000018bcce26150>
```

It looks all running at same thread, but is it guaranteed?

Comment: Re follow-up Realm question, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/49043257/1271826.

Answer (score 3):

To quote the docs on DispatchQueue:

> Dispatch queues are FIFO queues to which your application can submit tasks in the form of block objects. Dispatch queues execute tasks either serially or concurrently. Work submitted to dispatch queues executes on a pool of threads managed by the system. Except for the dispatch queue representing your app's main thread, the system makes no guarantees about which thread it uses to execute a task.

So no, it is expressly **not** guaranteed.

In fact, for a concurrent queue, I would expect the queue to have a pool of threads that run on different cores, and assign work to each thread in turn so that it could take advantage of having multiple cores.

Comment: i think realm needs to be runned at same thread all time

Comment: Yeah, even a serial queue does not ensure that subsequent tasks dispatched to the same serial queue will run on the same thread. Often it is, but not always.

Answer (score 0):

Duncan answered your question. But to illustrate the behavior:

```swift
let logger = Logger(subsystem: "Experiment", category: "GCD")

let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "serial", qos: .utility)

for numbers in 1...5 {
    queue.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(numbers)) {
        logger.debug("\(Thread.current)")
    }

    queue.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(numbers*2)){
        logger.debug("\(Thread.current)")
    }
}

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
    let start = CACurrentMediaTime()
    while CACurrentMediaTime() - start < 3 { }    // tie up the thread for a little time
}
```

That results in:

```
2022-01-17 09:08:09.378384-0800 MyApp[38526:14889044] [GCD] <NSThread: 0x600000711b80>{number = 6, name = (null)}
2022-01-17 09:08:10.378264-0800 MyApp[38526:14889045] [GCD] <NSThread: 0x60000074c540>{number = 5, name = (null)}
2022-01-17 09:08:10.378661-0800 MyApp[38526:14889045] [GCD] <NSThread: 0x60000074c540>{number = 5, name = (null)}
2022-01-17 09:08:11.378262-0800 MyApp[38526:14889046] [GCD] <NSThread: 0x6000007586c0>{number = 7, name = (null)}
2022-01-17 09:08:12.378305-0800 MyApp[38526:14889048] [GCD] <NSThread: 0x6000007454c0>{number = 3, name = (null)}
2022-01-17 09:08:12.378729-0800 MyApp[38526:14889048] [GCD] <NSThread: 0x6000007454c0>{number = 3, name = (null)}
2022-01-17 09:08:13.378357-0800 MyApp[38526:14889048] [GCD] <NSThread: 0x6000007454c0>{number = 3, name = (null)}
2022-01-17 09:08:14.378440-0800 MyApp[38526:14889048] [GCD] <NSThread: 0x6000007454c0>{number = 3, name = (null)}
2022-01-17 09:08:16.378463-0800 MyApp[38526:14889046] [GCD] <NSThread: 0x6000007586c0>{number = 7, name = (null)}
2022-01-17 09:08:18.378552-0800 MyApp[38526:14889046] [GCD] <NSThread: 0x6000007586c0>{number = 7, name = (null)}
```

Above, I am dispatching something else to a different queue of the same QoS to help manifest the problem, but this behavior could easily be manifested if any other subsystem within your app (or frameworks that your app uses) happened to use GCD, too. The above does not guarantee that a different thread will be used, but in my tests, it makes it easier to manifest the problem.

In short, the GCD documentation is explicit that there are no assurances as to which thread will be used, even for a serial queue.

---

Not that it matters, but the same is true if you use a GCD timer source on a serial queue, too. GCD is free to use whatever thread from its pool that it chooses (unless, obviously, if you specify the main queue).